# Дата без знаков Regex

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения, строки

Нужно проверить содержится ли в строке дата вида ДДММГГ (то есть без знаков - 131022). Вроде написал regex для каждой секции отдельно, а как теперь заставить это всё вместе работать одним шаблоном не знаю.

ДД - 0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]

ММ - 10|0[1-9]{1}|12{2}

ГГ - [0-9]{2}

Comment: `(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:10|0[1-9]{1}|12{2})[0-9]{2}` - попробуйте так. Посмотрите еще `[1-9]{1}` - без указания квантификатора ничего не изменится, {1} можно удалить,  `12{2}` здесь что-то не так, если вы не хотите получить 122, думаю тут просто нужно оставить 12 без квантификатора `{2}`

Comment: это можно и без регулярок сделать

Comment: Вроде работает, благодарю!

Comment: @aepot например как?

Comment: `string date = "301022"; if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "ddMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out _)) Console.WriteLine("ok"); else Console.WriteLine("fail");`

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, теперь буду знать